# How to print the content of a text file to STDOUT in Linux Assembly Language using c library functions?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, libc

First I tried opening a file with fopen function and print content of the file using fprint function but it was just printing a bunch of symbols to the terminal.

After a while I realized that it does not take pointer to a stream as argument and above mentioned behaviour was expected. **It was printing the actual pointer value.** putc or puts function also does not seem to take a pointer to the file I/O stream as an argument.

My best guess right now is I have to **access the buffer fopen function created somehow!** But I have no idea how or if it is possible. To sum it all up I am absolutely stuck right now.

The **ultimate goal** here is to get input from STDIN and/or a file do some processing on the text(eg: lowercase to uppercase) and output the result to STDOUT and/or a file. I figured If I am able to get the answer to above mentioned problem then It should help with the ultimate goal maybe.

PS: Let me know If the question can be improved in any way. Thank you.

Maybe the following code will help to get a better understanding of what I am trying to say.

```
.section .data
o_rdonly:
    .ascii "r"
content:
    .ascii "Content of the file: %d\n"  #This is how I figured what those random symbols were.

.section .bss
.lcomm buffer, 10

.section .text
.globl _start
_start:
    movl %esp, %ebp

    pushl $o_rdonly
    pushl 8(%ebp)
    call fopen

    ##Print the content of the file?##
    #pushl %eax #
    #call printf    #It just prints the actual address of the File I/O pointer.

    pushl $0
    call exit
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to first read from the file using `fread` or `fgets` or some other function and then write what you read to standard output.  There is no shortcut to directly print the contents of one file.

Comment: Does `sendfile(2)` not work with a TTY destination?  The man page says that since Linux kernel version 2.6.33, out_fd can be any file.  https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendfile.2.html.  (But I guess you meant in terms of C stdio functions, not Linux system calls or their glibc wrapper functions. And the querent says they want to eventually do some processing on the text so that wouldn't be a useful building block.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Technically `sendfile` is an option, but I'm sure that's not the point of the exercise.

Comment: Yeah, I first commented before reading the question body, just the title.

Comment: @PeterCordes Just to clarify the issue mentioned above is resolved.  `... call fopen pushl $5 pushl $0 pushl $0 pushl %ecx pushl $1 call sendfile...` Is this not the correct way? The function call is returning -1 any idea why it could be happening. PS I am finding the third paragraph from the description block really confusing. Could it be explained in a more beginer friendly manner maybe. Could this function be used to copy small files around in Linux? Thank you.

Comment: @Suresh `sendfile` wants file descriptors, not `FILE` pointers.  To obtain a file descriptor, either use `open` to open the file or use the `fileno` function to obtain the file descriptor of a `FILE` pointer.  Note that mixing stdio and direct file-descriptor IO on the same `FILE` is only permitted if you flush the file between each switch.

Comment: @Suresh Also note that you won't be able to achieve your *ultimate goal* using `sendfile`.  I recommend to not spend too much time on that.